perl: replacing all unicode x2103 (degree Celsius) in Perl6::Slurp-ed file
I am struggling with reading a UTF8 text file and replacing all occurrences of a unicode characters (degree Centigrade) with some other string.
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use 5.030;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use Perl6::Slurp;

my $s= "Hello.  This is 2.3℃ .";
$s =~ s/2.3/two-point-three /gms;
$s =~ s/\x{2103}/degrees celsius/gms;
print "STRING: '$s'\n";

my $fs= slurp("test.md");
$fs =~ s/2.3/two-point-three /gms;
$fs =~ s/\x{2103}/degrees celsius/gms;
print "FSYSTM: '$fs'";


and my test.md file reads just like the string.

Hello.  This is 2.3℃ .


Why is the output
STRING: 'Hello.  This is two-point-three degrees celsius .'
FSYSTM: 'Hello.  This is two-point-three ℃ .


Can you upload the test.md somewhere, then we can try to reproduce. The file may have some special encoding

Note that File::Slurper has a more intuitive interface.

You might also find that Path::Tiny is a useful alternative — among other things, it has a slurp_utf8() method.

You need to specify the file encoding when reading a non-ascii file using Perl6::Slurp:
The following works for me:
my $fs= slurp('<:utf8', "test.md");

This will read the file and then decode the content from UTF8 to Unicode such that Perl can work with it as Unicode, see perluniintro and  Perl6::Slurp documentation for more information.

Quibble: despite what it says in the SYNOPSIS, you probably want slurp('<:encoding(utf-8)', 'test.md');. The difference is that the latter actually checks for valid encoding, whereas the former assumes utf-8 regardless of the actual encoding of the file.
